# Group sorted array according a mean difference threshold

Tags: algorithm, statistics, computer-science

Problem statement: I have an array of `N` sorted integers and a threshold value `K`. I would like to group them in such a way that for each element, the difference between the group mean and the element is `<= K`. What is the best algorithm to use?

I've looked into Jenks' natural breaks and k-means clustering, but both of those seem better suited to a situation where you have a desired number of clusters, whereas I have a desired maximum variance per-cluster.

```
// example
const distances = [5, 8, 8, 9, 16, 20, 29, 42, 56, 57, 57, 58, 103, 104, 150, 167]
const threshold = 10

// desired output:
// cluster(distances) =>
// [
//   [8, 8, 9, 5, 16, 20]
//   [29, 42]
//   [56, 57, 57, 58]
//   [103, 104]
//   [150, 167]
// ]
```

Here's my progress so far: https://gist.github.com/qrohlf/785c667735171b7353702cc74c10857d

I'm probably going to try some kind of divide-and-conquer approach for correcting the 'ballpark' results I get from the implementation I currently have, but I don't really see a great, clean way to do this right now.

Comment: Why should 5 be put in separate cluster? If you have `[5, 8, 8, 9, 16, 20]`, the mean is 11, and there is no element smaller than 11-10=1 or larger than 11+10=21. Also `[150,167]` can be put in the same cluster, right?

Comment: @justhalf you're correct, my desired output is actually incorrect! I've updated the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I searched and I found this: **Unweighted Pair Group Method with Arithmetic Mean**.
Here is an article with an example: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPGMA). I think it will help you, It looks easy to confirm with your purpose.

The **UPGMA** algorithm produces rooted dendrograms and requires a constant-rate assumption - that is, it assumes an ultrametric tree in which the distances from the root to every branch tip are equal.

Comment: That looks very close to what I'm after. I'll give it a go!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what search engine/search terms led you to UPGMA? My stats/discrete math is a little fuzzy these days, so I'm guessing part of my difficulty in this area stems from not knowing the right query terms for a search.

Comment: I started from Cluster analysis and Data clustering algorithms. This link should be helpful: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis

Comment: It would be useful to add a few details about the method to the answer to make it more self-contained.

Comment: UPGMA was indeed exactly what I was after. I'm accepting this answer, but I've also added an answer with a simplified version of my implementation in JavaScript for those who want to see some code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44169907/381299

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else bumping into this, here's my (unoptimized) implementation of the UPGMA algorithm described above:

```js
const head = array => array[0]
const tail = array => array.slice(1)
const last = array => array[array.length - 1]
const sum = array => array.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
const avg = array => sum(array) / array.length
const minIndex = array => array.reduce((iMin, x, i) => x < array[iMin] ? i : iMin, 0)
const range = length => Array.apply(null, Array(length)).map((_, i) => i)
const isArray = Array.isArray

const distances = [5, 8, 8, 9, 16, 20, 29, 42, 56, 57, 57, 58, 103, 104, 150, 167, 800]

// cluster an array of numeric values such that the mean difference of each
// point within each cluster is within a threshold value
const cluster = (points, threshold = 10) => {
  return _cluster(points, range(points.length).map(i => [i]), threshold).map(c =>
    isArray(c) ? c.map(i => points[i]) : [points[c]])
}

// recursive call
const _cluster = (points, clusters, threshold) => {
  const matrix = getDistanceMatrix(points, clusters)
  // get the minimum col index for each row in the matrix
  const rowMinimums = matrix.map(minIndex)
  // get the index for the column containing the smallest distance
  const bestRow = minIndex(rowMinimums.map((col, row) => matrix[row][col]))
  const bestCol = rowMinimums[bestRow]
  const isValid = isValidCluster(points, mergeClusters(clusters[bestRow], clusters[bestCol]), threshold)

  if (!isValid) {
    return clusters
  }

  return _cluster(points, merge(clusters, bestRow, bestCol), threshold)
}

const isValidCluster = (points, cluster, threshold) => {
  // at this point, cluster is guaranteed to be an array, not a single point
  const distances = cluster.map(i => points[i])
  const mean = avg(distances)
  return distances.every(d => Math.abs(mean - d) <= threshold)
}

// immutable merge of indices a and b in clusters
const merge = (clusters, a, b) => {
  // merge two clusters by index
  const clusterA = clusters[a]
  const clusterB = clusters[b]
  // optimization opportunity: this filter is causing *another* iteration
  // of clusters.
  const withoutPoints = clusters.filter(c => c !== clusterA && c !== clusterB)

  return [mergeClusters(clusterA, clusterB)].concat(withoutPoints)
}

const mergeClusters = (clusterA, clusterB) => clusterA.concat(clusterB)

// optimization opportunity: this currently does 2x the work needed, since the
// distance from a->b is the same as the distance from b->a
const getDistanceMatrix = (points, clusters) => {
  // reduce clusters to distance/average distance
  const reduced = clusters.map(c => Array.isArray(c) ? avg(c.map(i => points[i])) : points[c])
  return reduced.map((i, row) => reduced.map((j, col) => (row === col) ? Infinity : Math.abs(j - i)))
}

const log2DArray = rows => console.log('[\n' + rows.map(row => '  [' + row.join(', ') + ']').join('\n') + '\n]')

console.log('clustered points:')
log2DArray(cluster(distances))
```